# How do I avoid greping matching lines with -

Tags: grep, regular-expression, pattern-matching

I'm trying to grab only matching lines from a file using grep. The problem is that, when for example I use the following expression:

```
grep -w AFFX-KIT-000088 textfile
```

it will return:

```
AFFX-KIT-000088-A
AFFX-KIT-000088
```

However, I only want the exactly matching expression AFFX-KIT-000088. I have already trying -F -E and quoting. The textfile where I need to grep the lines is very big and I can not modify it (this also means I need an answer that doesn't involve many steps as it would take forever to process).

*Note*:

The file is actually very big and has many columns (not only the one I'm using for grep).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -x 'AFFX-KIT-000088' file
```

The `-x` forces a match of a *complete* line.

You may also want to add `-F` as you are matching with a string, not a regular expression.  This would possibly speed up the operation.

The `-w` option does not work here as `-` is not a "word character".  The substring `AFFX-KIT-000088` in `AFFX-KIT-000088-A` is therefore a complete word.

"Word characters" are characters matching `[[:alnum:]_]`, i.e. alphanumerical characters and underscore.

---

In multi-column data, assuming tab-delimited fields and matching in column 3:

```
awk -F '\t' '$3 == "AFFX-KIT-000088"' file
```

That is, compare the 3rd field to a specific string.

When a condition like this lacks an associated action, the default action is to print the whole input record if the condition is *true*.  If you just want to print the field's data:

```
awk -F '\t' '$3 == "AFFX-KIT-000088" { print $3 }' file
```

Comment: Hi, I didn't menction because I thought I made it obvious by menctioning the file was very big, but the file has many columns (not only the one I'm using for grep), so I can not use -x. I have also tried -F but it doesn't seem to work. I'm, sure that the problem comes from - not being a word character, but the solution requires more informatic knowledge that I probably have have.

Comment: @PabloGarcíaGonzález Then you'd better update the question, or you'll get faulty answers like mine.

Comment: I will, thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: Okay, awk does the job perfectly fine. Thank you so much!